# Случайный код

Tags: javascript, html

Нужен скрипт, который будет генерировать случайный код из забитых, например 2 кода:
<script></script> и <html></html> нам надо чтобы скрипт иногда выкидывал <script></script>, а иногда <html></html>, все должно быть на HTML+Javascript, PHP нельзя

Comment: я все больше поражаюсь интересным заданиям.

Comment: @Shrek задание раз плюнуть, а вот как его описывают, это да) Гугль точно не ответит)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var code = new Array("//code 1","//code 2","//code 3");
var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * code.length);
document.write(code[rand]);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if((Math.random()).toFixed(0) == 0)
   document.write("script");
else
   document.write("html");
```

на javascript

Comment: это если не обращать внимания на то что вы хотите вывести)
я просто не вижу связи между <html></html>  и  <script></script>

Comment: я имею в виду скрипт, в котором забиты 2 кода, а он должен их случайно выводить, ну или хотя бы поочереди

Comment: ну тк вместо "document.write("script");" пиши свой любой код на javascript,
я написал - (Math.random()).toFixed(0) - это случайно число 0 или 1.
если это случ число 0, то выполнять document.write("script"), иначе выполнять document.write("html")
берешь свой код и вставляешь вместо document.write("script")...

или напиши конкретнее что тебе надо.

Comment: есть подозрение что автор хочет непрерывное выполнение каких то кусочков кода на страничке или нет???